# JavaFX - good or not? I need docking in it

Tags: java, user-interface, module, javafx, docking

I have just explore javaFX. I am now programming modul based application by netBeans platform. I have minimal UI now, but I am going to do quite complex GUI.
Is javaFX good for me? And if yes, how I can implement docking in main window?

(i think about usage of JFX becouse I want good looking app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends what you are trying to do. If you are building an interface using standard GUI components, then it might make sense to use Swing. You can build good looking apps with Swing, and you can build ugly apps with JavaFX.

Comment: so true, your needs should dictate the technology you will use.  If you are looking to create a desktop app go w/ swing, if you want to try and create a rich web app, then I would go w/ javafx or even flex.

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX is good you can try with it.
It will give your application cool look but its little bit heavy.

Answer (score 0):

Your real problems lies in using NetBeans platform. If you are using also NetBeans windows system then combining it with JavaFX is hard. The API needed to add Scene to JComponent is private. But look forward, we are always adding new features to NetBeans platform.

Answer (score 0):

A simple docking framework for JavaFX:

https://github.com/andy-goryachev/FxDock

```
public void start(Stage s) throws Exception
{
    // plug in custom windows and dockable panes. 
    FxDockFramework.setGenerator(new DemoPanes());

    // load saved layout
    int ct = FxDockFramework.loadLayout();
    if(ct == 0)
    {
        // when no saved layout exists, open the first window
        DemoWindow.openBrowser("https://github.com/andy-goryachev/FxDock");
    }
}
```